# Word VBA shows the encoding for an RTF as -1… what does that mean?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I've been trying to establish why a number of rtf files (opened and edited by multiple users from a network drive) have seen certain styles convert to Symbol or Wingdings fonts.

One lead I'm investigating is the file encoding (ActiveDocument.TextEncoding), which returns a result of -1 for all files. I couldn't find this on the MS list [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff860880.aspx). Can anyone tell me what the value of -1 means/translates to, please?

Comment: Not sure, but I believe "-1" indicates "not relevant" as TextEncoding is really about the encoding of .txt and other "plain text files on disk, not ".doc/.docx/.rtf files. RTF files obviously have an encoding (?cpg1252 on Windows) but once opened are treated as "Word documents" with a TextEncoding of -1

Comment: For the main problem, with the fonts, check in the Compatibility section of the Word Options if font substitution has taken place. Word will do this if the original font is not available in the configuration where the document is opened. The other thing that might give you some information is the actual font, itself: some fonts are tagged as "symbol" fonts and the type of substitution you're seeing may be due to this.

Comment: Thanks @CindyMeister (and bibadia too). I hadn't thought about font substitution, but I can see that it is in effect, eg Symbol has been substituted for Symbol (AS). I still don't understand how or why Symbol (AS) has replaced Times New Roman in the style definitions, but I doubt anyone can help me with that puzzle!

The bad news is that reapplying TNR leaves with a series of boxes, but the good news is that I've been able to restore earlier versions of the files without the 'rogue' fonts.